# Tangent equation divisible by (x-y)

Tags: derivatives, induction, proof-verification

I have attempted this proof but I am not sure is the induction step is correct any assistance would be appreciated also I am not sure if i have proved what I was trying to.

Let  $t(x)=f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)$

For $f(x)=x^n$

Show that $f(x)-t(x)=(x-y)^2p(x)$ for some $p(x)$ i.e that $f(x)-t(x)$ is divisble by $(x-y)^2$

I have tried to prove this with induction.
The case of $n=2$ is obvious as you get $(x^2-y^2)-2y(x-y)$ which cancels to $(x-y)^2$ therefore the conjecture holds for $n=2$

The induction step is just  assume for n=k 
$$(x^k-y^k)-ky^{k-1}(x-y)=(x-y)((
x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+...+xy^{k-2}+y^{k-1})-ky^{k-1})=(x-y)((
x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+...+xy^{k-2}-(k-1)y^{k-1}))|(x-y)$$

so for $n=k+1$ I get $$ (x-y)((
x^{k}+x^{k-1}y+...+xy^{k-1}-(k)y^{k}))=(x-y)((
x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+...+xy^{k-2}-(k-1)y^{k-1}))$$ which by the induction hypothesis IS divisible by $(x-y)$
so assume $n=k$ holds the $n=k+1$ will obviously hold so for all $n>1$ the conjecture holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you can't assume that
$$
f(x)-t(x) = (x-y)^2 p(x)
$$
In general you will have
$$
f(x)-t(x) = (x-y)^2 p(x,y)
$$

If you treat $f(x)-t(x)$ as a polynomial in $x$, you have to show that it has a double root at $x=y$.
Now
$$
\Delta(x)=f(x)-t(x) = x^n - y^n - n y^{n-1}(x-y)
$$
Clearly
$$
\left. \Delta(x) \right|_{x=y} = 0 \tag1
$$
and
$$
\left. \Delta(x)' \right|_{x=y} = \left. \left( n x^{n-1} - n y^{n-1}\right) \right|_{x=y} = 0 \tag2
$$
From (1) we have
$$
\Delta(x) = (x-y) \Phi(x,y)
$$
Denoting derivative with respect to $x$ by $'$
$$
\Delta'(x) =  \Phi(x,y) +(x-y) \Phi'(x,y)
$$
From (2) 
$$
\left. \Phi(x,y)\right|_{x=y} = 0 \Rightarrow \Phi(x,y) = (x-y) p(x,y)
$$
Hence the result.